# OpenLayers feature display service?

Tags: openlayers

is there any webservice that could display features on the map (openlayers) from PostGIS.

This would be the flow:

1. Map is shown
2. Features (points, polygons, multilines) are fetched from the server and displayed with info boxes if one exists
3. Server (PostGIS) gets update with new features
4. Map is refreshed with new data

Tnx.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I solved it.

1. GeoJson is provided through service.
2. Websocket is opened on the map and used to send "refresh" command
3. DB gets new points, send message through websocket, map updates according to that through GeoJson.

It works for me, cannot say that this is good approach, stay back - beware dragons there!